# NanoVNA software not showing impedance

Tags: vna, smith-chart

I am trying to use a NanoVNA to see the impedance on a Smith chart. But in the software I don't see any impedance value. Does anyone know how to get it to show up? I've tried the software on both Windows and Mac and it looks the same.

[image]

Comment: Question needs more info.  Measuring the impedance of what? How are you measuring (diagram would help)? Have you calibrated? How did you do that? Which software package? Have you confirmed the software is connected to the VNA?

Comment: I am measuring the impedance of a BLE inverted F antenna on a PCB. I connected an SMA cable from the nanoVNA to the PCB. I confirmed the measurement show up on the NanoVNA built in screen, I just can't get it to show up in the computer software. I am using the native software NanoVNA-QT (VNA View). I confirmed the software is connected because the SWR is correct, and the smith chart graphic is correct. I just can't figure out how to get it to show the impedance from any point in the smith chart

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to calibrate using the software. After I did each Short, Open, Load and then hit Apply the impedance showed up

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I needed to calibrate using the software. After I did each Short, Open, Load and then hit Apply the impedance showed up

Comment: Well done. I was about to suggest you give the nano vna saver application a try. https://nanovna.com/?page_id=90. I've been using it for a while and never had any issues.